# Strange phenomenon when declaring double

Tags: arduino-uno

**Consider this question closed, found my answer through the answers I had**

I am trying to make a position profile curve depending on Looptime, accelerationloops,Setposition,Currentposition(position) and velocity.
The curve should look like this:

[image]

Is someone able to check what is wrong with my code?

```
float array[30];

struct Formula {
  int LoopTime = 1000;
  int AccelerationLoops = 11;
  float VelocityLoop = 0;
  float VelocityFactor = 0;
  int TotalLoops = 0;
  float DeltaPosition = 0;
  int Setpoint = 0;
  int Iteration = -1;
  float EndOne = 1.25;
}Formula;

float SetPosition = 1404;
float Position = 0;
float Velocity = 36;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  for(Formula.Iteration ; Formula.Iteration <= Formula.TotalLoops; Formula.Iteration++){
    ProgFormula();
    Serial.println(Formula.Iteration);
    if(Formula.Iteration >= 0) {array[Formula.Iteration] = Formula.Setpoint;}
  }
  for(Formula.Iteration = 0 ; Formula.Iteration <= Formula.TotalLoops; Formula.Iteration++){
    //Serial.println(array[Formula.Iteration]);
  }                    
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}

void ProgFormula(){
  if(Formula.Iteration == -1) {
    Formula.DeltaPosition = SetPosition - Position;
    Formula.VelocityLoop = Velocity / (1000 / Formula.LoopTime);
    Formula.TotalLoops = Formula.DeltaPosition / Formula.VelocityLoop + Formula.AccelerationLoops;
    Formula.VelocityFactor = Formula.VelocityLoop * 0.5 / Formula.AccelerationLoops;
    Formula.EndOne = (Formula.VelocityFactor*pow(Formula.AccelerationLoops,2));                       
  }
  else if (Formula.Iteration >= 0 && Formula.Iteration <= Formula.AccelerationLoops) {
    Formula.Setpoint = Formula.VelocityFactor * pow(Formula.Iteration,2);
  }
  else if (Formula.Iteration > Formula.AccelerationLoops && Formula.Iteration <= (Formula.TotalLoops - Formula.AccelerationLoops)) {
    Formula.Setpoint = Formula.VelocityLoop * Formula.Iteration - Formula.EndOne;
  }
  else if (Formula.Iteration >= (Formula.TotalLoops - Formula.AccelerationLoops) && Formula.Iteration <= Formula.TotalLoops) {
    Formula.Setpoint = -Formula.VelocityFactor * pow((Formula.TotalLoops - Formula.Iteration),2) + Formula.DeltaPosition;
  }
  else {
    Formula.Setpoint = Formula.Setpoint;
  }
}
```

Comment: In setup(), `array[Formula.Iteration] = Formula.Setpoint` yields undefined bahavior when the index is −1.

Comment: Bit of a shame that i missed that... Edited my code, what is the reason my double values of the array are just integers with extra zero's?

Comment: In avr-gcc, `double` is the same size as `float`.

Comment: But in what way will that effect my results?

Comment: Please be more specific about what the problem is: What behavior do do expect from your code? What behavior do you have instead?

Comment: I am trying to make a motion profile for the position (edited my question).

Comment: If an answer provides the solution you want you should accept it. Also, writing an "answer found " message at the top is not what's done because the site is trying to build a set of matched questions and answers. So the 'green tick' when you accept serves the same purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this may not be a proper answer. I'm just having a hard time reading
your code, and I cannot understand why you make it so complicated. If
you know the acceleration profile, computing the position profile is
just a matter of integrating twice. Here is an example, not for Arduino
but for a PC. It should not be very different on an Arduino, you just
wouldn't use `printf()`:

```c++
/* Compute position for any acceleration profile. */
void compute_profile(float (*acceleration)(int), int max)
{
    float x = 0, v = 0;

    for (int t = 0; t <= max; t++) {
        v += acceleration(t);
        x += v;
        printf("%d\t%f\n", t, x);
    }
}

/* Your particular acceleration profile. */
float VttgJ(int t)
{
    if (t <  7) return t;
    if (t < 13) return 12 - t;
    if (t < 40) return 0;
    if (t < 46) return 39 - t;
    else        return t - 51;
}

int main(void)
{
    compute_profile(VttgJ, 50);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The user inputs the following: Position and Velocity. They both need to be controlled. Because this isn't possible I have build three different formules by integrating the velocity curve. The system is able to measure a position and has a constant looptime. My code is rather complex and can probably a lot shorter. Maybe a modification of your code will be a lot smaller.